# Effect of muscular excercise on height growth

Tags: muscle

I am 16 years old. .I am a bit less than 5 feet 7 inch.I want my height 6 feet.But I have just joined gym and started muscular excercise of triceps, biceps ,shoulder and chest to gain muscles.Will this really effect my height-growth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you seem to disregard your back and legs. If anything is going to set you up for failure, this is it. I know that you want a big barrel chest, proportioned arms, and even a six-pack. But how do you intend to be strong if your back and legs are weak?

To answer your question, though: No. The only thing that can potentially stunt your height growth, is poor dietary choices. Under proper supervision, you should follow a whole-body training program (not just upper body). Besides, working your lower body is going to be beneficial to your upper body goals because of better balance and skeletal development.

Sources:

- http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16437017
- http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19620931

Comment: thank you very much dear.....ur advice is very precious to me so i will definetely follow it from tomorrow....actually today was my first day at gym so i just excercised my upper body only but tomorrow it will be my back and leg's turn.....but friend,i just want to get sure that it would not affect my height growth...so please give me surity or some hard proof so that i can focus on my gyming in a right way....please dear please...i shall always be obliged to you....

Comment: @UjjvalNarang - I forgot to add my sources. I've edited my post with links to relevant studies.

Comment: @alec - Actually, there are quite a few things that can stunt growth. High cortisol due to prolonged stress, thyroid malfunctions, breaking the bone through the growth plate, nutrition (as you noted), a few other things as well.